# Out of sample prediction for rma object in metafor

Tags: r, regression, metafor

After a regression model has been estimated, it is typical to extract predicted values. But I can't figure out how to do this in `metafor::rma(`

```
library(metafor)

res <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg,
       mods = ~ ablat + year, 
       data=dat.bcg)

predict(res, 
    newdata = expand.grid(
      year = 1980,
      ablat = 30:55
      )
    )
```

which returns 13 fitted values (the rows in the data used to estimate the `rma` object, rather than the 25 rows in `expand.grid(` object.

How can I do out of sample predictions on a new `data.frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help file for `?predict.rma` specifies the parameter as `newmods` rather than `newdata` and it seems to require a matrix rather than a data.frame. This should work

```
predict(res, 
        newmods = as.matrix(expand.grid(
          ablat = 30:55,
          year = 1980
        ))
)
```